# Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while writing data

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to export data from bigquery to Google Cloud Storage while using  command.

```
EXPORT DATA OPTIONS(
  uri='gs://bucket/archivage-base/Bases archivees/*.csv',
  format='CSV',
  overwrite=true,
  header=true,
  field_delimiter=';') AS
SELECT * FROM `base-012021.creation_tables.dataext`
```

And I have this error: Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while writing data.

I cannot understand why because the service account seems to have all the grants. And i didn't find any topic that heps me to solve the problem

Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

If this is the live query you're using and you haven't redacted the real bucket name, it's probably because of the `bucket` string in the URI.  The URI should be something like `gs://your-bucket-name/prefix/path/to/output/yourfileprefix_*.csv`

If you have redacted the bucket name, then check to make sure that the user (or service account) identity issuing the query has the requisite access to the bucket and objects in cloud storage.

Comment: Thank you. The problem was the name of the bucket.

Answer (score 1):

i had same issue.
First, you need to check service acct in IAM. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80bfk.png)

after add, you create a file json Certification.  and add it in project